# What is the difference between this post methods in Zend?

Tags: zend-framework, post

I have this : `$this->view->post[]`  and this `$this->getRequest()->getPost()`. What is the difference between them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this->view->post = $variable;
```

This is the way you assign variables to your view so you can have access to it in your view script.

```
$data = $this->getRequest()->getPost()
```

This is the way you get data from a POST request that is coming to your server.